# Is there a standard way to wrap a string in an error? Also how do I make, box and return a custom error type?

Tags: error-handling, rust

I'm writing a basic program and putting the work in a 
`try_main` and then exiting with nonzero if `try_main` returns an `Error`.

The basic `try!` statements work, but I can't figure out how to return a custom error. First I tried to return a string wrapped in a standard error, then I tried to implement my own error type but it complained I was trying to return an error instead of a result.

Is there a standard way to wrap a string in an error? Also how do I make, box and return a custom error type?

```
fn main() {
    match try_main() {
        Ok(()) => {},
        Err(e) => {
            println!("thumbnail extractor failed with {:?}", e.description());
            std::process::exit(1);
            }
    }

}

fn try_main() -> Result<(), Box<std::error::Error>> { 
    let args : Vec<_> = std::env::args_os().collect();
    let filename = args.get(1).expect("needs one argument") ;
    println!("filename: {:?}", filename);


//  if !(filename.to_string_lossy().ends_with(".odf") || filename.to_string_lossy().ends_with(".ora"))
//  {
//      let s =  std::io::Error::new(Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, "This program only supports creating thumbnails from odf or ora files.".to_string()));
//      return s;
//  }   
    let f = try!(File::open(filename));

    let mut odf = try!(zip::ZipArchive::new(f));
    let thumb_name = r"Thumbnails/thumbnail.png";
    let mut thumb_file_in_zip = try!(odf.by_name(thumb_name).or(Err("could not find thumbnail zip file")));

    let mut fw = try!(File::create(r"thumbnail.png"));
    let mut buffer : Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    try!(thumb_file_in_zip.read_to_end(& mut buffer));
    try!(fw.write_all(buffer.as_slice()));
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: have you read [the book's paragraph](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/error-handling.html#the-result-type) on `Result`? And on [returning your own error type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/error-handling.html#defining-your-own-error-type) ?

Comment: Please [ask *one* question per question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/281829). Pick either "Is there a standard way to wrap a string in an error?" or "Also how do I make, box and return a custom error type?". Feel free to ask multiple top-level questions.

Answer (score 3):

`Result<T, E>` is an `enum` with two variants `Ok(T)` and `Err(E)`.

When you instantiate a `Result<T, E>` you will have to explicitly state which variant you want.

In your particular case you have to return `Err(s)` (given that `s` is of type `E`, you may have to use `Box::new` in your code, I haven't checked if `s` is correct, only that `Err` is missing).

One way to start using a custom error type is the following:

```
enum MyError {
    IoError,
    OtherError,
}

fn try_main() -> Result<(), MyError> {
    // do stuff
    return Err(MyError::IoError);
}
```

This is a simplistic approach, more on you'll probably want `impl std::error::Error for MyError` and `impl From<std::io::Error> for MyError`, possibly keeping the original error inside `MyError`. **Though this is optional.**

There's a [chapter on the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/error-handling.html) about error handling with much more details.